# Determine order of a Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $260$. For each prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, determine the order of a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

We have $|G| = 260 = 2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 13$.

Comment: The order of a subgroup is its size. The question you have posted doesn't ask how many subgroups there are, or whether they are normal.

Comment: Then I misinterpreted the question and I'll rework on it. But hypothetically, if the question did ask how many subgroups there are, how would I have done in answering that?

Comment: Note you can always have a single Sylow subgroup for a given prime (the cyclic group of order $260$ has just one subgroup of each order $r|260$)

Answer (score 1):

We have $|G| = 260 = 2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 13$

So $G$ contains at least one of the following:

- Sylow $2$-subgroup of order $4$
- Sylow $5$-subgroup of order $5$
- Sylow $13$-subgroup of order $13$

Comment: Yes, but note you might want to say "At least one..."