# Why can't a group of order 132 contain 3 Sylow $2$-subgroups and be simple?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, sylow-theory, simple-groups

In the question titled [Prove that if |G|=132 then G cannot be simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601673/prove-that-if-g-132-then-g-cannot-be-simple), it is shown a group of order $132$ cannot be simple. My summary of the proof:

- assume group is simple
- deduce the number of Sylow $11$- and $3$-subgroups ($12$ & $4$).
- deduece how many elements we have left to put into subgroups (we have used up $(11-1)\cdot12+(3-1)\cdot4=128)$, so we have $132-128=4$ left

I understand the proof up to this point. But then it continues:

> So then $n_3=4$. There are only $4$ remaining elements, which must
> comprise a Sylow $2$-subgroup which is unique and thus normal but this
> is a contradiction.

Here I don't follow. If we have assumed group is simple, that means there are no unique Sylow $p$-groups. If we did, that Sylow $p$-group would be normal, making $G$ not simple. I base this on the lemma I read about in [these notes](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/h/IB_L/groups_rings_and_modules/1_7) ([source code](https://github.com/dalcde/cam-notes/blob/06b2239b006f14d833cca2434190ebbf9a304bc6/IB_L/groups_rings_and_modules.tex#L1008) - see also the bottom of this question).

If I have $4$ elements left to deal with (including the identity), why cannot these be $a, b, c, I$ where $a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = I$?

Ie:

$$\mathrm{Syl}_2(G)=\{\{a,I\},\{b,I\},\{c,I\}\}$$

making $n_2=|\mathrm{Syl}_2(G)|=3$, which is allowed.

So no contradiction is found after assuming $G$ is simple. It is a problem though, since both the [referenced thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601673/prove-that-if-g-132-then-g-cannot-be-simple), and other sources I saw claim $G$ is not simple.

**What am I getting wrong?**

---

**Lemma:** If $n_p = 1$, then the Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal in $G$.

**Proof:** Let $P$ be the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup, and let $g \in G$, and consider $g^{-1}Pg$. Since this is isomorphic to $P$, we must have $|g^{-1} Pg| = p^a$, i.e. it is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Since there is only one, we must have $P = g^{-1}Pg$. So $P$ is normal.

Comment: By the way $n_3 = 4$ is impossible anyway in a simple group, because that would imply that there a nontrivial homomorphism to $S_4$.  In fact in a nonabelian finite simple group we must have $n_p \ge 5$ for all primes $p$ dividing the group order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only $4$ remaining elements,  and if there's more than one Sylow $2$ there would need to be more than $4$.

(Thus the Sylow $2$ subgroup is unique,  hence normal,  hence $G$ isn't simple.)

What you're getting wrong is that the Sylow $2$ has order $4$, not $2$.

Comment: Thank you. Sylow 2 having order 4 is aligned with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/723509/590567) I found now. I don't yet see why this is the case, trying to find out...

Comment: The Sylow $p$ subgroups have order $p^n$, where $n$ is the *highest* power of $p$ that divides the order of $G$.

Comment: Oh ok, it's because $132=2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot11=2^2\cdot3\cdot11$, and $\mathrm{Syl}_p(G) = \{P \leq G: |P| = p^a\}$ ([source](https://github.com/dalcde/cam-notes/blob/06b2239b006f14d833cca2434190ebbf9a304bc6/IB_L/groups_rings_and_modules.tex#L997)).

Comment: Got it now, thanks! :)